# Listview not updating after return from Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the following class and for some reason, when menu item1 is selected, I launch a new Activity. When the activity returns, it calls onActivityResult() and inside that function I am trying to refresh my ListView. Unfortunately, for some odd reason, it is not updating the list. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? When I run it through the debugger and set a breakpoint in onActivityResult(), it does indeed hit the function correctly, after the activity closes. It just seems the line "m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChange()" seems to do nothing.

```
public class RestaurantZoom extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<FoodItem> m_FoodItems;
    private Context m_Context;
    private FoodItemAdapter m_Adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        m_Context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foodchooser);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitleShow);

        m_FoodItems = ((ArrayList<FoodItem>) this.getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("FoodItems"));
        tvName.setText(this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("RestaurantName"));

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        m_Adapter = new FoodItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_FoodItems);
        lv.setAdapter(m_Adapter);
        // lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arbys_logo_small);
        // lv.setCacheColorHint(0);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int index, long arg) {
                FoodItem fi = (FoodItem) av.getAdapter().getItem(index);

                Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, ItemZoom.class);
                i.putExtra("FoodItem", fi);
                try {
                    startActivity(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Exception ex = e;
                }
            }
        });

        // SetCheckedItems(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SetCheckedItems(menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void SetCheckedItems(Menu c) {
        MenuItem itemBad = c.findItem(R.id.item2);
        MenuItem itemGood = c.findItem(R.id.item3);

        String PrefFile = getString(R.string.prefname);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PrefFile, 0);
        boolean BadChecked = settings.getBoolean("BadChecked", false);
        boolean GoodChecked = settings.getBoolean("GoodChecked", false);
        itemBad.setChecked(BadChecked);
        itemGood.setChecked(GoodChecked);

        // ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // m_Adapter = new FoodItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row,
        // m_FoodItems);
        // lv.setAdapter(m_Adapter);
        m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;        
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        /*ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        m_Adapter = new FoodItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_FoodItems);
        lv.setAdapter(m_Adapter);
        ((BaseAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.invalidate();*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, Options.class);

            try {
                // startActivity(i);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Exception ex = e;
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            if (item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            String PrefFile = getString(R.string.prefname);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PrefFile, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("BadChecked", item.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            if (item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            String PrefFile2 = getString(R.string.prefname);
            SharedPreferences settings2 = getSharedPreferences(PrefFile2, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings2.edit();
            editor2.putBoolean("GoodChecked", item.isChecked());
            editor2.commit();
            m_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the code for my custom adapter:

```
public class FoodItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodItem> {
    private ArrayList<FoodItem> m_items;
    private Context m_Context;

    public FoodItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<FoodItem> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.m_items = items;
        m_Context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) m_Context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        FoodItem fi = m_items.get(position);
        //if (fi != null) {
            TextView tvTop = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTextTop);
            TextView tvBottom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTextBottom);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.loMainLayout);
            String PrefFile = m_Context.getString(R.string.prefname);
            SharedPreferences settings = m_Context.getSharedPreferences(PrefFile, 0);

            boolean BadChecked = settings.getBoolean("BadChecked", false);
            boolean GoodChecked = settings.getBoolean("GoodChecked", false);
            int SpinnerValue1 = settings.getInt("Spinner1Value", 0);
            int SpinnerValue2 = settings.getInt("Spinner2Value", 0);
            float NutValue1 = settings.getFloat("NutValue1", 200f);
            float NutValue2 = settings.getFloat("NutValue2", 100f);
            float BaseValue = 0.0f;
            boolean BadHighlighted = false;
            boolean GoodHighlighted = false;

            if (BadChecked)
            {
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 0)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCalories();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 1)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetFat();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 2)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSatFat();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 3)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetTransFat();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 4)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetFat();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 5)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCholesterol();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 6)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSodium();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 7)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCarbs();              
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 8)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSugar();
                if (SpinnerValue1 == 9)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetProtein();
                if (BaseValue >= NutValue1) {
                    lv.setBackgroundColor(0xff440000);
                    BadHighlighted=true;
                }
            }
            if (GoodChecked)
            {
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 0)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCalories();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 1)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetFat();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 2)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSatFat();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 3)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetTransFat();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 4)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetFat();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 5)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCholesterol();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 6)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSodium();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 7)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetCarbs();              
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 8)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetSugar();
                if (SpinnerValue2 == 9)
                    BaseValue = fi.GetProtein();
                if (BaseValue <= NutValue2) {
                    lv.setBackgroundColor(0xff004400);
                    GoodHighlighted=true;
                }
                if ((BaseValue <= NutValue2) && (BadHighlighted))
                    lv.setBackgroundColor(0xff552200);
            }
            if (!BadChecked && !GoodChecked)
            {
                lv.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
            }
            if (GoodHighlighted == false && BadHighlighted==false)
            {
                lv.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
            }
            //lv.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
            tvTop.setText(fi.GetFoodItem());

            String QuickView = "<b>Calories:</b> " + (new DecimalFormat("#.#")).format(fi.GetCalories());
            QuickView = QuickView + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Fat:</b> " + (new DecimalFormat("#.#")).format(fi.GetFat()) + "g";
            QuickView = QuickView + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Carbs:</b> " + (new DecimalFormat("#.#")).format(fi.GetCarbs()) + "g";
            tvBottom.setText(Html.fromHtml(QuickView));

            if (!fi.GetFoodIcon().equals(""))
            {
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("hamburger_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("chicken_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.chicken_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("fish_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("fries_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fries_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("salad_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.salad_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("onion_rings_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.onion_rings_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("soft_drink_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.soft_drink_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("drink_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.soft_drink_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("milkshake_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.milkshake_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("cake_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cake_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("breakfast_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bacon_eggs_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("hotdog_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotdog_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("root_beer_float_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.root_beer_float_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("slush_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.slush_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("wing_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.wing_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("ice_cream_cone_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice_cream_cone_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("ice_cream_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice_cream_cone_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("smoothie_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.smoothie_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("sub_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("sandwich_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sandwich_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("soup_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.soup_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("potato_chips_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.potato_chips_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("pizza_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizza_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("taco_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.taco_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("burrito_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.burrito_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("nachos_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.nachos_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("noodles_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noodles_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("tomato_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.tomato_icon);
                }
                if (fi.GetFoodIcon().equals("beef_icon"))
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.beef_icon);
                }
            } else {
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        //}
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` simply tells the adapter to notify the view to reload its contents...

> Notifies the attached View that the underlying data has been changed and it should refresh itself.

You need to update the adapter before calling this otherwise the view will simply reload the same data from the adapter.

Comment: If you look at my code above, you will see that I have some commented code in the onActivityResult() function. The commented code does rebuild a new adapter and I tried doing that, but it still doesn't seem to update. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @icemanind: Yep, I saw that and figured you may have already tried it. Without seeing code for how `FoodItemAdapter` works, however, I don't know what else to suggest. Are you sure that creating a new `FoodItemAdapter` in `onActivityResult(...)` should correctly query for new data?

Comment: Well what I am doing is I have a customer Adapter, FoodItemAdapter. What it does is it highlights certain rows (changed the background color of the row) depending on the number of Calories a food has. So there is no actual change in data, per se. What is actually changing is the rows that get highlighted or not. I will post the Adapter code for you to look at. Thanks for the help so far, by the way!